# Soma de duas tabelas e exibição de resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas nesse trecho e não consigo resolver " mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result",

```
$Valor = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT SUM(Y) AS TotalY AND SUM(X) AS TotalX FROM tabela");
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($Valor)){
$X = $rs['Y'];
$Y = $rs['Y'];
}
```

Teria algum meio de subtrair uma pela outra já dentro da primeira linha?

Comment: Já experimentou tirar o AND e colocar uma vírgula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Valor = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT (SUM(Y) - SUM(X)) AS Resultado FROM tabela");
if($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($Valor)){
$X = $rs['Resultado'];
}
```

Isso resolve o seu problema.